# Removing each row that possesses a singleton in the first column

Tags: awk, sed, word-processing

I would like to remove each row that possesses a singleton in the first column. e.g.

Input: Letters represent variables of which there may be thousands. Numbers represent columns and rows. There are multiple columns (not shown here).

```
    1.
1.  A
2.  B
3.  C
4.  C
5.  D
6.  E
7.  A
8.  H
9.  D
10. D
```

Output:

```
     1.
 1.  A
 3.  C
 4.  C
 5.  D
 7.  A
 9.  D
10.  D
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got understood your expectation.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{s[$1]++;next}
     (s[$1]>1){ printf("%2d. %s\n",FNR,$0)
}' infile infile
 1.  A  another_column  ...
 3.  C  ... 
 4.  C  ...
 5.  D  ...
 7.  A  ...
 9.  D  ...
10.  D  ...
```

If you don't want record's number come in result, use the command as following:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{s[$1]++;next} (s[$1]>1)' infile infile
 A  another_column  ...
 C  ... 
 C  ...
 D  ...
 A  ...
 D  ...
 D  ...
```

Comment: (1) You probably don’t need the `$1 in s` test; everything that’s in the file will be in the array by the end of the first pass.  (Or are you handling an edge case that I don’t see?) (2) The question is unclear, but my guess would be that the OP doesn’t really want line numbers written to the output file.